# How can I suppress zero or nonzero values in a matrix?

Tags: matrix, output-formatting

So, if I have something like:

```
 F[IdentityMatrix[3] // MatrixForm, 1]
```

I'd like `F[]` to display:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 &   &   \\
  & 1 &   \\
  &   & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

I'm looking for a function that works for any matrix, and basically filters out all but one value.  This will make it easy for me to scan through a matrix, since the function will do most of the work for me.

Comment: Looking through the documentation, it looks like `GridBox' is a good candidate to use for displaying the matrix.

Comment: If it is just for display purposes then `IdentityMatrix[3] /. 0 -> "" // MatrixForm `

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch:  Correct me if I'm wrong, but that only filters out the zero.  I'm looking to filter out _every_ value except for a chosen value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
f[x_List, n_] := (x /. y_ /; y != n -> " ") // MatrixForm

f[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}, 7]
```

If you need to display only elements in list `n`, then use:

```
g[x_List, n_List] := x /. y_ /; (MemberQ[Complement[Flatten[x], n], y]) -> " " // 
  MatrixForm

g[{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}, {3,7}]
```

I'm sure there's a more elegant way to do this last transformation, but the obvious ones involving `!MemberQ[n,y]` or `FreeQ[n,y]` somehow didn't work.

Comment: I would suggest you re-title your question:  "How to suppress display of chosen elements in a matrix" or something like that, since "zero or non-zero" conveys no meaning.

Answer (score 15):

You can also use `MapAt` with `Invisible` or `Style[#,White]&`:

```
f1 = MatrixForm[MapAt[Invisible, #, Position[#, Except[#2], {2}, Heads->False]]] &;(*or*)
f1 = MatrixForm[MapAt[Style[#,White]&, #, Position[#, Except[#2], {2}, Heads->False]]] &;
```

Example:

```
m = RandomInteger[5, {5, 5}];
Row[Prepend[f1[m, #] & /@ {1, 2, 1 | 2}, MatrixForm[m]], Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

**Update:** Using `Manipulate` to toggle the elements to show:

```
mf1 = Manipulate[f1[#, Alternatives @@ show] // Style[#, 20] &, 
                 {{show, {1}}, Union@Flatten@#, TogglerBar}, Alignment -> Center] &;
```

Example:

```
m = RandomChoice[Range[0, 20], {5, 10}];
mf1@m
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Here's a variation you might find useful:

```
fn[a_?ArrayQ, x_] :=
  Replace[a, p : Except[x] :> Style[p, White], {ArrayDepth@a}] // MatrixForm
```

Now:

```
fn[IdentityMatrix[3], 1]
```

[image]

But because the non-selected elements are only styled white they appear when selected:

[image]

Comment: Nice touch, +1.

Comment: `Mouseover` might be a good idea too.

Answer (score 5):

```
m = RandomInteger[3, {5, 5}];

ReplaceAt[m, x : Except[3] :> Invisible[x], {All, All}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
ReplaceAt[m, x : Except[1 | 2] :> Invisible[x], {All, All}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]